# C++ OpenCV max/argmax for 3D matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a three-dimensional intensity volume of size `256 x 256 x 256` and I want to perform an max/argmax operation, i.e., I want to estimate the maximum in the third dimension and the corresponding index using OpenCV in C++.

What is the fastest way to perform these operations?

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

void maxArgMax(const cv::Mat &volIn, cv::mat &imMagOut, cv::Mat &imIdxOut)
{
    // what to do here?
}

int main()
{
    int dims[] = { 256, 256, 256 };
    cv::Mat vol(3, dims, CV_32FC1);

    cv::Mat imMag(dims[0], dims[1], CV_32FC1, vol.at<float>(0)); // this should include the max. magnitude
    cv::Mat imIdx(dims[0], dims[1], CV_8UC1); // this should include the corresponding index

    maxArgMax(vol, imMag, imIdx);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: say "argmax" in the title, then people understand your goal instantly.

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum in the 3rd dimension"? Do you mean your result is a 2D matrix?

Comment: @Micka The two matrices `imMag` and `imIdx` are 2D matrices with the same width and height of the 3D matrix. Consider `i` and `j` are the indices of the first and second dimension, respectively. For each `i` and `j`, I want to find the maximum along the third dimension and the corresponding index, i.e., `imMag[i, j]` contains the max. magnitude and `imIdx[i, j]` contains the index.

Comment: perhaps the C++ equivalent of `np.argmax(image_stack, axis=0)` (if stacked as NHWC). OpenCV's cv::Mat is weird when you aren't using it as a multi-channel 2D image but as a 3D tensor. -- it may be necessary to actually write loops here... copy the values into a std::vector, then operate on it. `minMaxLoc` expects to work in the WH plane. perhaps with some slicing tricks you may be able to offer it an 1D slice of your cube (repeated calls)

Comment: perhaps reformulate this _not_ as a 3D tensor, but as a 2D image with 256 channels (opencv allows upto 512 channels). then the memory layout of your data is a lot more convenient: the slices you're considering would be *contiguous*. that helps a lot with OpenCV because it's not smart enough to have general strides in its Mat objects. -- I don't even know if OpenCV can transpose 3D tensors (like numpy can)

Comment: there's `Mat cv::Mat::operator()(const std::vector<Range> &ranges) const` which may allow you to slice along the dimension you want, in your 3D tensor, for every (i,j). then `minMaxLoc` _might_ be able to work on this.

Comment: @brnk ok, got it. Not sure whether cv::max can be used if you use a 256-channel matrix: I think I remember that in some functions there are "reduction strategies" which specify how data along channels, rows or columns are aggregated, but I dont remember in detail. If you'll have to implement the functions yourself, biggest impact should have caching, which should be ok for 256-channel matrix (all 256 values of one position are next to each other in memory) but isn't ok for 3D matrix (here, the distance is much bigger).

Comment: have a look at: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa87ea34d99bcc5bf9695048355163da0 will this work? This should give the index along that axis. You would have to fill your dst matrix according to those indices afterwards. Not sure whether this is the fastest solution, maybe you could have a look at the source code and fill both in the same run: indices and values ;)